# When was first line detection algorithm created and when line detection problem was posed?

Tags: algorithm, line, detection

I wonder when was first line detection algorithm created (first used in practice and refrenced by any publications) and when line detection problem was posed (I know it can look like generaal edge detection problem but it is quite more complex than that)?

Comment: If you don't restrict the terms of your search, probably you should consider the works of Euclid, Thales and Newton, to say the less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my approach for your question:

- First, I searched [line detection](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=line%20detection) in Google Scholar.

The first 2 returned results are:

> A study of retrospective and on-line event detection
>
> New prospects in line detection by dynamic programming

- Second, I opened the [2nd link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=491623), as the 1st is obviously unrelated.
- Third, I searched for one of most oldest references in that paper.
- Fourth, that paper (Linear Feature Extraction and Description) is shared by [USC](http://iris.usc.edu/Outlines/papers/1980/nevatia-babu-cgip-80.pdf), and enjoys [528-times](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Linear%20feature%20extraction%20and%20description) references according to Google Scholar.

According to the introduction part of the paper and the reference count, it seems to be the one of the oldest ones for line (not just edge) detection.

Comment: Well...) Grate answer - I did not even knew that google has such grate service... But: some students (including me) were trained that line detection is achevable by Hough transform. Wiki history page talls us that The Hough transform was patented as U.S. Patent 3,069,654 in 1962 and assigned to the U.S. and he used it scince 59... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#History  and that is not even problem posting - thats like a solution... so... What shall I do?

Comment: @Blender, I do not understand _what shall I do_. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Blender, I am not sure but I guess: according to [Term of Patent, US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States), the term was 17 years at that time, and 1962 + 17 = 1979. That is why earliest papers appeared in 1980. (Earliest papers on Hough Transform also appeared in early 1980s, according to Google Scholar.)

Comment: Well there is [Straight-Line Detection with Diodes](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/freesrchabstract.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5245707&queryText%3Dline+detection%26openedRefinements%3D*%26sortType%3Dasc_Publication+Year%26searchField%3DSearch+All) but I do not currently have IEEE access... but it is dated 1934... link does not work..(

Comment: @Blender, what are you looking for in that paper? [IEEE link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5316742)